# Bootstrap Date Range Picker -> Single Date Picker: How to set a Date

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, momentjs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm experimenting with [Boootstrap Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)

Whats the best way to set Date into a **Single Date Picker** via Javascript?

Single Date Picker initialization code

```
$(#date).daterangepicker({
    locale: {
          format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    },
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true
});
```

I tried with below code:

```
$("date").data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(data.startDate);
```

This way, I'm getting below output, which is not really acceptable!!!
[image]

Hope someone come up with a nice solution.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$("date").data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(data.startDate);
$("date").data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(data.startDate);
```

That is the only way I can find so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Set Date:

```
$(#date).daterangepicker({
    locale: {
          format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    },
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    startDate: '2020/03/04',
    startDate: '2020/03/04'
});
```

Reset date:

```
$("#date").data('daterangepicker').setStartDate('2020/03/04'); 
$("#date").data('daterangepicker').setEndDate('2020/03/04');
```

If u gonna reset current date:

```
$("#date").data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(moment()); 
$("#date").data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(moment());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case. The issue was in the startDate format, it was not matching with the format given in locale:{format:'DD/MM/YYYY'}